# How to use J2AB?

Tags: android, java-me, j2ab

I have an application in J2ME ,I want to convert that application to Android, using J2AB (J2Android Bridge), kindly give me a method for that? Also give another method if exit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [J2me App Runner](http://www.netmite.com/android/) on Android. I dont know in J2AB.

If you are developing means use [LWUIT framework](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html) and develop Midlet application on android. But you have to learn LWUIT before you can use.

Comment: AFAIK you can't add Pure j2me application. Because You cant add LCDUI form with LWUIT. There is no tool or API which can conver the J2ME code/classes to the LWUIT classes. You have to write the code in LWUIT itself. LWUIT is swing based UI framework for j2me.